# Subspace Topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to teach myself topology by doing proofs of things I come across in my reading. I'm having some trouble proving the statement below:

Let $(Y,U)$ be a subspace of $(X,T)$. Then, $U$ is a subset of $T$ if and only if $Y$ is an element of $T$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It’s an if-and-only-if result; have you made any progress on either direction of the proof?

Comment: I know that U = {V intersect Y : V is an element of X}, and this is where I thought I should start for the forward direction...but I don't know what to do from here. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If $U$ is a subset of $T$, then $Y \in U$ by definition of a topology, so $Y \in T$ by assumption.

Assume $Y \in T$. Then, by definition, $U$ is the following subset of $T$ : $\{ V \cap Y \mid V \in T \}$. This subset is in $T$ precisely because $Y \in T$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helped.

Answer (score 0):

$U=\{Y\cap t: t\in T\}.$ We have $Y\in U$ because $X\in T$ and $Y=Y\cap X\in U.$

(1). $U\subset T\implies Y\in U\subset T\implies Y\in T.$

(2). $Y\in T \implies  \forall t\in T\;(Y\cap t\in T)\implies U\subset T.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, definitely helped.